# Apache Cordova Facebook login issue

Tags: android, facebook, cordova

I have an apache cordova app that I am using facebook login on.  When I launch the app on the virtual device I can login to facebook, because I know what the url is and can add it in the facebook developer app settings.  But when I launch the app on my phone and try to login I get the "Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings." error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mv8Uq.png)

Basically I have no idea what url to put in my facebook settings, because I have no idea what the url is when the app is launched on the phone.  Anyone know what the base url is for cordova apps?

On a side note, I know there is an option to add another platform where I could add an adroid device.  I don't know if this is what I am supposed to do for cordova apps.  I am using the javascript facebook sdk so I just figured adding a website to the app settings was the correct way to go.

Comment: if you are using cordova mobile application...the why are you using web login... try to use the native login with cordova plugin...

Comment: every time I install the facebook connect plugin my app gets compiling errors saying it can't find some images and won't build

Comment: Any update on this brother ?